# Shapefiles are nested tmap object

Tags: r, shapefile, r-sf

I got a shapefile from the The Italian National Institute of Statistics (`CAMERA_PLURI_2017.shp` within this zipfile here: https://www.istat.it/storage/COLLEGI_ELETTORALI_2017.zip)

I try to read the shp file itself. A number of maps appear be be nested in the shape object as 'variables'. How do I access each individually?

```
require(sf)
italia <- read_sf("CAMERA_PLURI_2017.shp")
plot(italia)
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Look into GDAL & OGR. They are open source and allow you to work with/query shapefiles easily

Comment: There is usually a wrapper for most languages to include GDAL. Python especially. But I’ve also used C# & nodeJS to call a bat file with a gdal command and get the response from that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you seem to be using the R package {sf} there is no need to call GDAL & OGR directly; it is handled by the sf package behind the scenes.

What you do need is use standard R tools to select a variable (sf package uses a modified `data.frame` format, which is pretty standard in R).

There are a number of possibilities - either the $ notation, or the [ notation, but I suggest {tidyverse} approach, such as the following piece of code:

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

italia <- read_sf("CAMERA_PLURI_2017.shp")

popolazione <- italia %>% 
   select(POP_2011)

plot(popolazione)
```

[image]